# Node.js and DevTools autosave

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Did anyone have this problem? I'm trying to use Node.js and DevTools autosave, my path details in Chrome are:

Match:

```
http://localhost:49387/
```

Save To: F:\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\

Servers:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9104/
```

Node and DevTools have loaded correctly. When I load the page and select an element and change colour, in node.js I get the following:

> Saved a stylesheet to F:\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Content/site.css
>   4301:         color: #fffrgb(240, 24, 24);

But when I close the browser and open again nothing changes. Did anyone else have this problem or does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Strange it seems to be working now, not sure why